# Make objects appear to vibrate in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut

What is the best way to make objects appear to vibrate in OpenGL?
I have a collection of cubes which I want to "vibrate" with varying intensity, and I'm assuming the best way to do this is to just slightly move the position in which they are rendered. Should I use a timer to achieve this or is there a better way?
Here is my simple drawCube function:

```
void drawCube(float x, float y, float z, float opacity, float col[], float shake)
{
    glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
    glColor4f(col[0], col[1], col[2], opacity);
    glutWireCube(20);
    glTranslatef(x, y, z);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that a vibration basically is a movement too fast for our eyes:
Yes, you need to move the cube for this.

This will be convincing as long as your application runs at high enough frame rates.
With low frame rates (~15 fps and lower) you'd need other trickery.

As for the *how to do it*: I would suggest a simple function driven by a timer to simply calculate the translation for the current frame.

One easy function to use here is `sin`, which also represents clear soundwaves (= vibrations in air).

given a double/float `time` , that represent the seconds since start of the application (and the fraction representing the milliseconds)

```
void drawCube(float x, float y, float z, float opacity, float col[], float time)
{
    float offset = sin(2.0f * 3.14159265359f * time); // 1 Hz, for more Hz just multiply with higher value than 2.0f
    glTranslatef(-x + offset, -y + offset, -z + offset);
    glColor4f(col[0], col[1], col[2], opacity);
    glutWireCube(20);
    glTranslatef(x, y, z);
}
```

Edit: this would *vibrate* it in the interval [-1,1] around the original position. For a bigger vibration multiply the result of `sin` with a scaling factor.

Comment: Quick question, what is the significance of the figure 3.14159265359f?
I realise its pi, but what would happen if I changed this value?

Comment: That's PI. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi chaging that value would increase or decrease the speed of the vibration. i just used it to simulate 1 Hz accurately, it has no real value for a simple vibration.

Answer (score 1):

Personnally, I would use `rand()` or my own implimentation of. Maybe a [Noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) function.
I would use that noise function to obtain a random, or psudo random, offset in the range of [-1, 1].
and then multiply that by the `shake` variable you have there.

```
// returns a "random" value between -1.0f and 1.0f
float Noise()
{
    // make the number
}

void drawCube(float x, float y, float z, float opacity, float col[], float shake)
{
    float x, y, z;
    ox = Noise();
    oy = Noise();
    oz = Noise();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef( x + (shake * ox), y + (shake * oy), z + (shake * oz) );

        glColor4f(col[0], col[1], col[2], opacity);
        glutWireCube(20);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Something you may have noticed I adjusted, was I added in `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix`. They are very usefull, and will automatically reverse anything done between them.

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(1, 1, 1);
    // draw something at the location (1, 1, 1)

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(2, 2, 2);
        // draw something at the location (3, 3, 3)

    glPopMatrix();
    // draw at the location (1, 1, 1) again
glPopMatrix()
```